# How do I change the format of my date columns, in my data frame and then subtract the dates from each other, using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Python Data frame in excel file]

1. How do I change the date formats to YYYY/MM/DD for each date column in the data frame, illustrated, using python?
2. How do I create a new column within the data frame called, "time difference between dates" by subtracting the "Applied Date" column from the "Hired Date" column.

Comment: how the date difference should look like? share the expected output

Comment: did the answer helped?

Comment: @Naveed Hey, so when I apply the code in python, the dates aren't changed into the format that is desired. I am wondering whether this is because the date is originally seen as an "object" in python and not a "string"? Or should this not make a difference?

Comment: if you share the data as a code (preferably) or as a text. I'll be able to share the result on your data. Please refer to the StackOverflow guidelines in sharing reproducible example

Comment: @Naveed No worries, there was an error on my side. I replicated your code in Python and everything works now. Thank you! Just had one last question. You converted the format of the two date columns in two steps. Is there a way to convert the format of the date columns in one go, rather than having one line for every date column I had. i.e. if I had 5 date columns, would I have to replicate the code 5 times?

Comment: updated the solution to convert multiple dates in a single statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you share the data as a code (preferably) or as a text. I'll be able to share the result on your data.
Please refer to the StackOverflow guidelines in shareing [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
# for converting to the YYYY/MM/DD Format
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
df['date2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date2']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')


# for calculating the difference b/w two dates
pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])
```

alternately,

```
# list of the date columns to convert
dates= ['date','date2'] 

# apply conversion to each of dates in the list
df[dates] = df[dates].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))


# for calculating the difference b/w two dates
pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])
```